# rails 3 button_to :remote => true, what should the controller action look like

Tags: ruby-on-rails, button

what should the controller action look like for a button_to with :remote => true.

I am new to ajax reqs so I don't know what I am doing.  as I understand it, the :remote => true sets it up to be an ajax request.

```
<%= button_to "Generate Code", add_code_band_path(@band), :method => :post, :remote => true %>
```

My current action:

```
  def add_code
      @band = Band.find(params[:id])
      if user_signed_in?
        @code = current_user.codes.build(params[:code])

        respond_to do |format|
        if @code.save
            format.html { redirect_to @band, notice: 'Reward was successfully created.' }
            format.json { render json: @band, status: :created, location: @band }
          else
            format.html { render action: "show" }
            format.json { render json: @band.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
      else
        redirect_to @band, :alert => "Your Not Logged In! You must be logged in to create a code"
      end
    end
```

Comment: no error but the screen refreshes...

Answer (score 8):

You can't use redirect_to with Ajax calls. You should do something like this to redirect (when using ajax):

```
render :js => "window.location = 'path_to_redirect_to'"
```

If the problem still persists, try including format.js, in your respond to block.

Comment: format.js{ render :js => "window.location = 'path_to_redirect_to'" }

Answer (score 0):

If the page is just refreshing as you mentioned, ensure you have included and are correctly referencing the unobtrusive scripting adapter for jQuery (if you're using jQuery that is.)

https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs